# Tokenize text - Very slow when doing it

Tags: python, performance, nltk, spacy

**Question**

I have a data frame with +90,000 rows and with a column ['text'] that contains the text of some news.

The length of the text has an average of 3.000 words and when I pass the word_tokenize it makes it very slow, Which could be a more efficent method to do it?

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
df['tokenized_text'] = df.iloc[0:10]['texto'].apply(word_tokenize) 
df.head()
```

Also word_tokenize hasn't some punctuations and other characters that I don't want, so I created a function to filter them where I'm using spacy.

```py
from spacy.lang.es.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
spanish_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('spanish'))
otherCharacters = ['`','�',' ','\xa0']
def tokenize(phrase):
    sentence_tokens = []
    tokenized_phrase = nlp(phrase)
    for token in tokenized_phrase:
        if ~token.is_punct or ~token.is_stop or ~(token.text.lower() in spanish_stopwords) or ~(token.text.lower() in otherCharacters) or ~(token.text.lower() in STOP_WORDS):
            sentence_tokens.append(token.text.lower())
    return sentence_tokens
```

Any other better method to do it?

Thanks for reading my maybe noob‍ question, have a nice day.

**Appreciations**

1. nlp is defined before

```py
import spacy
import es_core_news_sm
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
```

2. I'm using spacy to tokenize but also using the nltk stop_words for spanish language.

Comment: where do you define `nlp`? is it `Spacy` or `nltk`?

Comment: @Green I'm using my own function that use spacy nlp, that I defined before like this ```python
import spacy
import es_core_news_sm
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
```

I'm using nltk spanish stop words and also spacy to delete the most I can

Comment: and do you only need to tokenize?

Comment: @Green Yeah, I want now to tokenize them to plot the most common words

Comment: If any of the answers did help you, please accept it

Comment: @Green I was testing both, thanks for the help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `spacy` faster when you only wish to tokenize.
you can change:

```
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
```

To:

```
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm", disable=["tagger", "ner", "parser"])
```

A small explanation:
Spacy gives a full language model which not merely tokenize your sentence but also do parsing, and pos and ner tagging. when actually most of the calculation time is being done for the other tasks (parse tree, pos, ner) and not the tokenization which is actually much 'lighter' task, computation wise.
But, as you can see spacy allow you to use only what you actually need and by that save you some time.

Another thing, you can make your function more efferent by lowering token only once and add the stop word to spacy (even if you didn't want to do so, the fact that `otherCharacters`  is a list and not a set is not very efficient ).

I would also add this:

```
for w in stopwords.words('spanish'):
    nlp.vocab[w].is_stop = True
for w in otherCharacters:
    nlp.vocab[w].is_stop = True
for w in STOP_WORDS:
    nlp.vocab[w].is_stop = True
```

and than:

```
for token in tokenized_phrase:
    if not token.is_punct and  not token.is_stop:
        sentence_tokens.append(token.text.lower())
```

Comment: As a note, this kind of syntax for disabling components was only used in spacy v1.x. See the v1.x API: http://legacy.spacy.io/docs/api/language#call and the v2.0 migration guide https://spacy.io/usage/v2#migrating-languages

Answer (score 2):

If you are only tokenizing, use a blank model (which only contains a tokenizer) instead of `es_core_news_sm`:

```py
nlp = spacy.blank("es")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't now about spacy.blank() I will search more about it